# Connecting to MongoDB console, and database template

Tags: mongodb

I'm working through this tutorial:

https://medium.com/@matejhlavacka/6-in-6-challenge-week-1-yik-yak-web-clone-81938f3a033e

I'm unable to have the templates appear on my app, and I think I'm being held up on the two commands telling you to open a MongoDB console and type meteor mongo, and input this code:

db.yaks.insert({yak:"first yak ever"});

I've tried to download robomongo and sifted through many other resources, but still can't figure out why my page looks like below, rather than showing links:

http://wordofmouth.meteor.com/

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks all,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a template named "Home". The first argument after `this.render` is the name of the template.

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  // 'Home' is the name of the template
  this.render('Home', {
    data: function () { return Items.findOne({_id: this.params._id}); }
  });
});
```

You should have something like

```
<template name="Home">
</template>
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried to change the html file I built called yaks_list.html to read <template name="Home">, but that didn't fix the problem

Comment: Check the error message in your console. It says `template is not defined`. Click on the link to go to where in the JS that error is coming from. It should be `Template`.

Comment: And you need to post your router file, your template html, and your template JS.